# How to get file information in google drive using google drive url in google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

Does anyone know if this is possible?

i think i can do it by extracting id from url.
then execute code like below.

```
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name,parents,owners)",q="'drive id' in parents"
    ).execute()
```

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files

however parsing url might fail sometime.
so i would like to know how to get file information in drive by specify url.

Comment: About `i think i can do it by extracting id from url.`, can you provide the sample URL you expect?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure the parsing URL will not fail, you can use the `findall` function in  `regex` in extracting the folder ID from the folder URL. Since the structure of the folder URL is static except for the `id` part, this pattern will guarantee the extraction of folder Id

### Regex Pattern

```
"/folders\/(.*)\?resourcekey"
```

Please see sample code below for getting the files in a specific folder in my google drive

### Code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.colab import auth
from google.auth import default
import re

auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()

# Build the service
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
# Google drive folder's URL
folder_url = 'https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/folders/1bBWIXbinmb-DQ1z_fspsvxlw3vt8v6Wa?resourcekey=0-3Q_nXWmlLp_eG79NzcRe5w'

# Get the folder's ID from the URL using regex
folder_id = re.findall("/folders\/(.*)\?resourcekey", folder_url)
#query
query = f"'{folder_id[0]}' in parents"

# List the files in the folder
results = service.files().list(pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name,parents,owners)",q=query).execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

if not items:
  print('No files found.')
else:
  print('Files:')
for item in items:
  print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

### Output:

[image]

### Resources:

[Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files)

[Regular Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

https://regex101.com/

Comment: thanks! If it's possible, I would like to use the url as it is. do you know the way?

Comment: Unfortunately `drive API` does not have a method that uses the raw URL for getting the list of files. Also the `files.list` method has no parameters for that. You can visit this link for the complete documentation of google drive files and folders management (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-files)